# Android: Update the existing Contact Photo

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying update existing contact through my app. The contacts is updating successfully without an image. When I try to update contacts with image that time it is not updating image.

This is the code that I am using for adding photo.

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if(contact_bitmap!=null){          
                contact_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
                byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.parseInt(idValue))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.DATA15,b)
                        .build());

                try {
                    stream.flush();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        try {
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "Contacts Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "Please try again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Can anyone please help me
Thanks in advance :)